# Usage of myself vs me

Tags: grammar, personal-pronouns

"Please summit your registration forms to John, Jay, or myself before the end of the day."

My homework says "myself" is incorrect and "me" should be used in the context of this sentence. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

*Myself* should be used

- in a reflexive sense: the subject and object are the same.

  > I shot myself in the foot.
  >   I bought myself a present.
- in an emphatic sense: the "self" is mentioned twice.

  > As for myself, I'll have chocolate mousse with cream.

In all other cases, *me* would suffice, and is preferable as it is shorter, neutral, and more traditional.  Overuse of *myself* is common, but is frowned upon by [grammarians](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2007/07/self-improvement.html) and [journalists](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2013/02/grammar) alike.

In your example, "myself" is incorrect because the action is neither reflexive nor emphatic.

Answer (score 0):

When 'me' or 'I' can be used in the sentence, one can avoid the usage of myself.

Also, myself is usually used when "I' has been used in the same sentence.In informal English, beginning a sentence with “myself” to express an opinion is widely accepted: “Myself, I can’t stand dried parmesan cheese.”

Source : http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/myself.html

Comment: Of course "one can avoid" does not mean "incorrect". You could have avoided each and every word in your answer, but that doesn't make it gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically speaking, it's due to the fact that the action of submitting would not be by the speaker in this phrase, so he should not use a reflexive pronoun.

However in spoken, it's very common to use, as it sounds more formal (although grammatically incorrect)

Hope this helps!