# making video of me answering questions vs making video of myself answering questions

Tags: pronouns, reflexives

I wonder what the correct use of the following phrase is?

> I'm making the video of me answering several questions...

I thought that this was the only way to say it. However, I came up with an alternative:

> I'm making the video of myself answering several questions...

What option is correct in terms of English grammar?

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions already here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182452/usage-of-myself-vs-me https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8257/rules-for-the-usage-of-me-vs-myself https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134572/which-prepositions-are-followed-by-accusative-pronouns-instead-of-reflexive-pron

Comment: While I prefer the sound of 'myself' here (I tend towards the formal when not being whimsical), 'I'm making a video of Tim, Alice, Bill, Ali and me on the roller-coaster' sounds far more natural than the alternative. These are grey areas, and saying one option is ungrammatical is often hyperprescriptive.

Comment: Which meaning do you intend? “I’m making a video of myself that answers several questions…” or “I’m making a video that shows me answering several questions”